# No puedo entrar en Internet debido a ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: android-studio

Veran, quiero hacer un programa que me lleve a una pagina web (www.marca.com para el ejemplo).

Para eso, tengo este codigo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webkit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Y este codigo Java:

```
package com.example.pcx.cliente;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView browser=findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        browser.setWebViewClient(new MiControl());
        String cad="<html><body><a href='http://www.marca.com'>Visitar Marca</a></body></html>";
        browser.loadData(cad,"text/html","UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Y aqui el codigo MiControl.java:

```
package com.example.pcx.cliente;


import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MiControl extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView browser, String url){
            browser.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Si omito la parte de la llamada a la clase MiControl.java, funciona de forma esperable, pero cuando incluso esta clase, me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que habre hecho mal?

Comment: ¿Tienes agregado permiso para internet en el `Manifest`? Algo así: **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que darle permisos a tu aplicación para poder acceder a Internet.

Esto se consigue abriendo el fichero:

> AndroidManifest.xml

y añadiendo la siguiente linea:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Ahora si que logro entrar en la pagina sin que salte el mensajito de error.